# Weird encoded error when using wp_generate_attachment_metadata()

Tags: images, media

I'm AJAX POST-ing images to Wordpress from another server and using a script to upload them into the Wordpress file system.

I get a strange output/error for the AJAX response, which I've narrowed down to the line: `$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filepath);`

[image: Error output]

I then further narrowed down the error to this line within the wp_generate_attachment_metadata() function:

```
$metadata['sizes'] = $editor->multi_resize( $sizes );
```

Any ideas on why this would happen, or how to encode the error so I can read it clearly? (I have a UTF-8 header on the script)

Comment: Are the data correctly enconded server-side? Can you check the charset value of the `Content-Type` in the HTTP headers of the response?

Comment: @cybmeta - It shows Content-Encoding:gzip, Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: The error maybe generate from [`wp_get_image_editor`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_image_editor), as WordPress say _The path parameter should be a local file (such as /var/www/wordpress/some/directory/image). In some cases using a url as the parameter will work, but depending on the server setup and firewalls, fetching the url of the image may or may not work!!_

Comment: @Jevuska - What's weird is that the image is uploaded just fine prior to that line of code. It's only when resizing the image through multi_resize that I get the error.

Comment: I just realised that what you are showing in the image **is not the results of `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` function**. This function returns a PHP array. What you are showing is a very different thing. Check your self with `var_dump( wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filepath) );`.

Comment: @cybmeta - That's what is so confusing, I'm not outputting the results of wp_generate_attachment_metadata() but it's still giving that error. If I do the var_dump as you suggested, the resulting array (which is correct) appears at the end of that long error message.

Comment: Your question is now a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It is obvious to me that you are wrong in the research you have done looking for the cause of the problem. It is not in that function, as you have seen using `var_dump()`. Please, reword your question and add code that we can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @cybmeta - If I comment out that function, the error goes away. I comment out each line after it one by one, the error stops only when I reach that line. And as I said, I even went further into that function and found the line within it that causes the errors to show.

Comment: You have a problem with the ouput of your code. **You think** the problem is with some function, then you ask about that function instead of asking about your real problem. Even worst, you have admit that you don't output the result of the function and you have checked the direct result of the function and it is ok. So, again, please give us code that we can use to reproduce the issue. We can not answer your question as it is. Give us the context because the function alone is not the problem. I hope you understand.

Comment: @cybmeta - The problem was in that function, just so know going forward. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It may be there but in your context, which you don't show to us nor explain; definetely you don't understand that. Imposible to give you an answer without the context.

Answer (score 1):

I tracked the error down through several functions to GD's `imagejpeg()` function.

So I checked the error log and found this:

```
HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections
```

A quick search found that this resulted from using a full URL instead of a server filepath. So I changed the  value of `$filepath` to use `$wp_upload_dir['path']` instead of `$wp_upload_dir['url']`

Problem solved :)

Comment: That is exactly what @Jevuska said in his comment. Read it.+1 for answering your own question. And, as you see, we needed the context I was asking for in the comments.